# The karate.jsonPath is not working even if the JSON Path is valid

Tags: api, testing, karate

**My script below:**

```
    * def inputJson = createJson();
    * print inputJson

    * def customerName = karate.jsonPath(inputJson, "$.customerDetails[0]")
    * print customerName
```

**Gives me this error:**

```
javascript evaluation failed: karate.jsonPath(inputJson, "$.customerDetails[0]"), Property ['customerDetails'] not found in path $
```

**Eventhough the jsonPath is valid as shown below:**

[image: Json path is working]

Wondering if anyone here has encountered the same? Could you kindly advise me how to rectify this? Thank you in advance.

**Note:** I printed the json in the console and used the same when I checked the jsonPath in my screenshot above. I also validated in JSON Lint the json I was using and it is a valid one.

Comment: downvoting because you used images. I would have tried if there was a sample JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will take note of this going forward. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JsonPath in this case:

```
* def customerName = inputJson.customerDetails[0]
```

But if you have trouble with JsonPath, try `karate.filter()` as an alternative:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897131/143475

Comment: Yup, noticed that the simple one works (no need for jsonPath). My issue got resolved by modifying my java method. I have one more question though.

Can the callonce be used with JS function? My JS returns json and I don't want to create json every time I run my scenarios. I only want to do the json creation once. Thank you!

Comment: @Drachir yes it should work - note that you can even load the JSON in `karate-config.js` and search for something called `karate.callSingle()` in the docs